# custom gitconfig for the session

Tags: git, config

I want to load a specific `.gitconfig` only for the current session.
I tried

```
git config -f ~/path/to/my/.gitconfig
```

but it only answers by the man page:

```
usage: git config [<options>]

Config file location
    --global              use global config file
    --system              use system config file
    --local               use repository config file
etc.
```

I also tried

```
GIT_CONFIG=/path/to/my/.gitconfig
```

but it is not taken into account.

EDIT: In this question, "current session" means "current bash session".

Comment: What do you mean with session? Do you want to have different configurations in different local clones, or different behaviour in the same clone on the same machine for different processes?

Comment: @rudi. I made an edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from [git version 2.32.0](https://git-scm.com/docs/git/2.32.0), you can set the environment variable `GIT_CONFIG_GLOBAL` in order to redirect to a different file than ~/.gitconfig. This version also introduces the variable `GIT_CONFIG_SYSTEM`, which would override `/etc/gitconfig`.

With git versions before, you can kind of simulate the same behavior, by unsetting $HOME, and set $XDG_CONFIG_HOME to a directory which contains a git folder with a config file residing in it. But I would advice against touching $HOME, since this will also affecting any program git runs itself. Also the git developers made it extremely hard to skip any $HOME/.gitconfig file, so there is not really much you could do if your are stuck with an older version.

~/.gitconfig

```
[alias]
foo = !foo
```

different-config

```
[alias]
foo = !bar
```

In an interactive session you can see the difference:

```
$ git help foo
'foo' is aliased to '!foo'

$ GIT_CONFIG_GLOBAL=/path/to/different-config git help foo
'foo' is aliased to '!bar'
```

So I would suggest to set `GIT_CONFIG_GLOBAL` to the desired file, which then will get read instead of ~/.gitconfig. Note that a `.git/config` will still be read, and everything in `.git/config` will take precedence over the `GIT_CONFIG_GLOBAL` file.

Comment: Works thanks. For the record: bash: `export GIT_CONFIG_GLOBAL=/path/to/.gitconfig2 && git diff` in the [fish](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/fish_for_bash_users.html) the command is `set -gx GIT_CONFIG_GLOBAL /path/to/.gitconfig2 && git diff`

Answer (score 0):

1. `git config` without any action just prints the help page you see. Do something with the config file, for example

```bash
git config -f ~/path/to/my/.gitconfig --list
```

2. Try `export GIT_CONFIG` to use the environment variables in subprocesses. Not exported environment variables are available only to the current shell but not in subprocesses.

Comment: `git config -f etc.` does not make the work. My aim is to be taken into account for the next git command like `git diff`.

Comment: I think that the environment variable GIT_CONFIG is deprecated (read here and there on the internet). Anyway, it does not seem to be taken into account.

Comment: @LaurentClaessens If GIT_CONFIG is deprecated and will be removed there will be no other way to set the path to the config without using `-f`. Tried exporting?

Comment: Yes, I tried with `export`

Comment: @LaurentClaessens Both `git config -f` and `export GIT_CONFIG` work for me.